# What is the recommended way to use vue-router after authenticating users?

Tags: vue-router

Say I just started a vue-nodejs-webpack simple project with vue cli:

```
vue create xxx
```

How should I plug its default client-side routing to allow certain routes based on authentication? in the most idomatic way?

My App.vue will look something like this:

```
<template>
  <v-app class="grey lighten-4">
    <Navbar />

    <v-content class="mx-4 mb-4">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-content>

  </v-app>
</template>
```

Whereas "Navbar" is a simple top navigation menu, and router-view simply shows content based on current route.

Route.js will look like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Dashboard from './views/Dashboard.vue'
import Projects from './views/Projects.vue'
import Team from './views/Team.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'dashboard',
      component: Dashboard
    },
    {
      path: '/projects',
      name: 'projects',
      component: Projects
    },
    {
      path: '/team',
      name: 'team',
      component: Team
    }

  ]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In roter.js, you can use [vue-router hooks](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) to have precise control on route whether to render components or not

Here in the below example `isAunthenticated` is a separate javascript function which returns boolean, by checking in the backend whether the user is authenticated or nor

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!isAuthenticated) next('/login')
  else next()
})
```

At the same time you can also use pre router hooks to prevent the user to enter specific route

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        // ...
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Also you can use [In-Component Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) at specific components to verify whether the user has specific access to this component or not